# Python - How to sum all combinations of a list of numbers in order to reach a goal. Use of number is optional

Tags: python, sum, combinations, permutation

I have a list of numbers

```
lis = [497.96, 10, 5084, 156.43, 381.3, 3298.85, 625.68]
```

that I would like to sum in various ways in order to try and reach the goal number of 8276. I also need to see whether throwing away the cents or rounding helps reaching the goal. Note that use of a number is optional.

I tried

```
from itertools import combinations
lis = [497.96, 10, 5084, 156.43, 381.3, 3298.85, 625.68]
for i in xrange(1, len(lis) + 1):   #xrange will return the values 1,2,3,4 in this loop
    if sum(list(combinations(lis, i))) == 8276:
       print list(combinations(lis, i))
```

but this gives me

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

which I'm not sure why or how to fix.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the numbers in the number list?

Comment: And can we use a number 'n' number of times? Because, 8276 cannot be reached with the input set, if we can use the numbers only once.

Comment: Hi Super, since you mentioned insight in roundings was also what you want, I posted a solution to show an arbitrary number of closest matches. Please mention if that is what you meant, or you if only want an *exact match*. The latter will have no output in your example.

Comment: Hey Super, although my solution is much longer than others, it does look for an exact match even when considering ignoring cents or rounding. Because of the requirement when cents can be ignored or rounded, it made the solution more complex. By they way, there was no exact match for 8276.

Comment: Don't need to preserve the order and a number can only be used once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention:

> I also need to see whether throwing away the cents or rounding helps reaching the goal.

..the code below will show the closest n- combinations, and the absolute difference they show to the targeted number.

Works on both `python3`and `python2`

```
from itertools import combinations
# set the number of closest combinations to show, the targeted number and the list
show = 5
target = 8276
lis = [497.96, 10, 5084, 156.43, 381.3, 3298.85, 625.68]

diffs = []
for n in range(1, len(lis)+1):
    numbers = combinations(lis, n)
    # list the combinations and their absolute difference to target
    for combi in numbers:
        diffs.append([combi, abs(target - sum(combi))])

diffs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

for item in diffs[:show]:
    print(item[0], round(item[1],10))
```

The output will show the top- n closest combinations (combination / absolute difference to the targeted number):

```
(5084, 3298.85) 106.85
(10, 5084, 3298.85) 116.85
(5084, 156.43, 3298.85) 263.28
(10, 5084, 156.43, 3298.85) 273.28
(5084, 381.3, 3298.85) 488.15
```

This shows that the closest you can get is `(5084, 3298.85)`, showing a difference of `106.85`.

---

#### Note

See btw [Note on floating point calculation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

---

### Edit

For the sport of it, a condensed version of the above script:

```py
from itertools import combinations 
# set the number of closest combinations to show, the targeted number and the list
show = 5
target = 8276
lis = [497.96, 10, 5084, 156.43, 381.3, 3298.85, 625.68]

diffs = [item for sublist in [[
    [combi, abs(target - sum(combi))] for combi in combinations(lis, n)
     ] for n in range(1, len(lis)+1)] for item in sublist]

diffs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
[print(item[0], round(item[1],10)) for item in diffs[:show]]
```

Comment: I think the question is about how to get the absolute number and a combination rather than how close we can make combinations. In the OP code, it is == 8276, rather than <=8276.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam I agree the code suggests that, but then *"I also need to see whether throwing away the cents or rounding helps reaching the goal."*  makes me believe he could use the closest match. "Rounding" is not defined on what. You could be right though.

Comment: I manually summed the numbers with various combinations and found that if the numbers cannot be used again, it is impossible to get the 8276 by any way. Guess OP has to clarify that as well, I guess.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam exactly that is the output of my code.

Comment: @thiruvenkadam I agree with your interpretation of the OP's question (return the combination that results in the exact sum). Do you think my answer addresses the OP's question?

Comment: @Joe based on my interpretation, your answer is right. However, OP has to come back to say what we think is right :)

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to sum all the combinations with given length instead of calculating a sum of a single combination. Instead you should loop over the combinations and check the sum for each one:

```
from itertools import combinations
lis = [497.96, 10, 5084, 156.43, 381.3, 3298.85, 625.68]
for i in xrange(1, len(lis) + 1):
    for comb in combinations(lis, i):
       if sum(comb) == 8276:
           print comb
```

The reason for the specific error is that [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) takes optional argument `start` which is the default value. If argument is not provided it defaults to `0`. Essentially your original code is trying to do following:

```
>>> sum([(1,), (2,)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify Python 2 or 3 but to run the above code in Python 3 change `xrange` to `range` and `print comb` to `print(comb)`.

Comment: Also `if sum(comb) == 8276` may fail to match combinations that 'should' sum to 8276, because of rounding errors. Try modifying the above code to print every combination and its sum and you'll see that some of the results are e.g. `6247.410000000001`. You could use e.g. `if abs(sum(comb) - 8276) < 0.01` to fix this.

Comment: @nekomatic The version is implicitly defined as 2.7 by `xrange` and `print` used in original question. Rounding problem could also be fixed by simply multiplying all numbers with `100` or using [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) but I guess the point of the question was the error mentioned in it.

Comment: @niemmi I agree with you. The question was tagged as "python" only (and not "python 2-7", etc). I think the OP doesn't care is it's python 2 or python 3, and is more concerned with solving permutations and combinations issues and output errors. I'm upvoting your comment/answer. I also agree with you that if there are floating math issues, then multiply everything by 100 and just do Integer math only as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you want to consider the cases where you can throw away the cents, or you can round to the nearest whole number. This requirement turned a simple solution to a pretty complicated one. In order to account for the above requirement, I expanded each number to include the additional possible cases. The expanded list shows the new list to get the combinations:

```
import math
import itertools as it
tolerance = 150
target_sum = 8392
found = False
lis = [497.96, 10, 5084, 156.43, 381.3, 3298.85, 625.68]

def add_throw_and_round(num):
    num_list = [num]
    if int(num) != float(num):
        num_list.append(math.floor(num))
    if round(num) not in num_list:
        num_list.append(round(num))
    return sorted(num_list)

lis_expanded = map(add_throw_and_round, lis)
print "Expanded list:\n", lis_expanded, "\n\nTarget sum:\n", target_sum, "\n"
for n in range(1,len(lis) + 1):  # n is number of summands in pick
    lis_combos = it.combinations(lis_expanded, n)
    for lis_combo_n in lis_combos:
        for combo_n in (it.product(*lis_combo_n)):
            sum_ = sum(combo_n)
            if sum_ == target_sum:
                found = True
                answer = combo_n
            if sum_ > target_sum - tolerance and sum_ < target_sum + tolerance:
                print "sum:", sum_, "\tCombination: ", combo_n
if found:
    print "\nThere is a match: ", answer
else:
    print "\nNo exact match found"
```

So I decided to show all sums that was within 150 of the target sum, just to see if it was working. There were no matches were the sum was exactly 8276:

```
>>> 
===== RESTART: C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/scripts/Stack_overflow/cents_py2.py =====

Expanded list:
[[497.0, 497.96, 498.0], [10], [5084], [156.0, 156.43], [381.0, 381.3], [3298.0, 3298.85, 3299.0], [625.0, 625.68, 626.0]] 

Target sum:
8276 

sum: 8382.0     Combination:  (5084, 3298.0)
sum: 8382.85    Combination:  (5084, 3298.85)
sum: 8383.0     Combination:  (5084, 3299.0)
sum: 8392.0     Combination:  (10, 5084, 3298.0)
sum: 8392.85    Combination:  (10, 5084, 3298.85)
sum: 8393.0     Combination:  (10, 5084, 3299.0)

No exact match found
>>>
```

Notice above that it tests cases where cents are thrown out, and rounded.
Just to test whether it will report a match when the target sum does match, I tried target_sum = 8392 because the output shows one combination should match it. So here is the output in that case:

```
>>> 
===== RESTART: C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/scripts/Stack_overflow/cents_py2.py =====
Expanded list:
[[497.0, 497.96, 498.0], [10], [5084], [156.0, 156.43], [381.0, 381.3], [3298.0, 3298.85, 3299.0], [625.0, 625.68, 626.0]] 

Target sum:
8392 

sum: 8382.0     Combination:  (5084, 3298.0)
sum: 8382.85    Combination:  (5084, 3298.85)
sum: 8383.0     Combination:  (5084, 3299.0)
sum: 8392.0     Combination:  (10, 5084, 3298.0)
sum: 8392.85    Combination:  (10, 5084, 3298.85)
sum: 8393.0     Combination:  (10, 5084, 3299.0)
sum: 8538.0     Combination:  (5084, 156.0, 3298.0)
sum: 8538.85    Combination:  (5084, 156.0, 3298.85)
sum: 8539.0     Combination:  (5084, 156.0, 3299.0)
sum: 8538.43    Combination:  (5084, 156.43, 3298.0)
sum: 8539.28    Combination:  (5084, 156.43, 3298.85)
sum: 8539.43    Combination:  (5084, 156.43, 3299.0)

There is a match:  (10, 5084, 3298.0)
>>>
```